# Где найти видео курс по jsp

Tags: java, jsp

Желательно, в котором создают сайт с логином, маленьким блогом и какими-нибудь апплетами.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вбей в google: Developing Enterprise Application using EJB. Web programing with Servlets and JSP.